# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre acc y val_acc en model.fit()?

Tags: redes-neuronales, keras

Intento crear un red neuronal con una capa de memoria larga a corto plazo para clasificar los comentarios tóxicos para [la competencia Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge). Utilizo `model.fit()` para entrenar mi modelo, pero hay cosas que aparecen en la pantalla que no entiendo:

[image: captura de pantalla de los resultados de model.fit]

Por ejemplo, ¿cuáles son las diferencias entre `acc` y `val_acc`?

Me fui a visitar [la página oficial sobre `model.fit()`](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjWypSLl-_ZAhUMchQKHXK7A6kQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkeras.io%2Fmodels%2Fsequential%2F&usg=AOvVaw1I4kR3VDn2c_PgIqyYb0-k) pero no me dice nada al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia:

- `acc` es la precisión calculada en el conjunto de entrenamiento (datos que el modelo ha podido ver con anterioridad).
- `val_acc` es la precisión calculada en el conjunto de validación (es decir, sobre datos que el modelo "nunca ha visto").

Si lo que quieres es estimar la habilidad de tu modelo para generalizar a partir de nuevos datos, entonces tienes que fijarte en la precisión de validación (`val_acc`) porque el conjunto de validación contiene datos que el modelo nunca ha visto durante el entrenamiento y por lo tanto no los ha podido memorizar.

Si la precisión en los datos de entrenamiento (`acc`) mejora continuamente, mientras la precisión en los datos de validación (`val_acc`) empeora, entonces seguramente estás sobreajustando (*overfitting*), es decir, tu modelo estaría empezando a memorizar los datos.

---

Fuentes (en inglés):

- [How to tell which Keras model is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34702041/3695983)
- [What's the difference between acc and val_acc](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/357)